# Spinner dropdown list added at what android api level??

Tags: android

What exact Android version was the spinner dropdown list (instead of the dialog) added to the android platform?? Can't seem to find this anywhere..

Thanks

Comment: it's not available in api 10 gingerbread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was added in API 11 (HoneyComb). But you can still use it on older versions, e.g. by using the `ActionBarSherlock` IcsSpinner or the `HoloEveryWhere` spinner.

Comment: that's what I thought, but then how come it's often referred to at the ICS Spinner?? or is this just something I got wrong?

Comment: Hmm, really? Let me check on the emulator. I am sure it's API 11 since they first used it in the ActionBar (which was introduced in HC). @pst the classes of course existed in API 9 but that's for the dialog spinner, not the drop down.

Comment: Just checked, it *is* available from HC+. @Jakob Don't know why it is called IcsSpinner though.